# How to pass Multiple key value pair data from one html to another Html page

Tags: jquery

I have got some key value pair data present in one html file , how can i pass this key value pair data to another html file ??

(I have got all this values under a div)

This is a mobile application being developed under phonegap
When googling i have seen 3 solutions for this

1. URL parameters
2. Cookie
3. Local Storage

I cannot go for URL parameters as each key has multiple values 
For example name as itself got , picture  description  .

I cannot go for Cookie as i have heard that PhoneGap doesn't suppourt Cookies .

I am new to LocalStorage , what are its pros and cons .

Please share your valuable ideas .

Comment: Are you able to do anything server side?

Comment: No , this is pure client side itself , there is n server involved at all .

Comment: Can you do it as an SPA (single-page application) i.e. all other pages are loaded via Ajax. Then you simply store your data in global variables and they are accessible to all pages while the app is running.

Comment: what about this link , http://www.plus2net.com/html_tutorial/submit-two.php  will that work for me ??

Comment: That being the case, @TrueBlueAussie would be the way to go that would be easiest for you to take care of your problem.